# Using your own model in train (caret package)?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use train from Caret with a package which is not included, and I get an error that I don't manage to figure out, any idea ? I used the [following link](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/www/custom_models.html?revision=847&root=caret#Illustration1) to get started

```
bmsMeth<-list(type="Regression",library="BMS",loop=NULL,prob=NULL) 
prm<-data.frame(parameter="mprior.size",class="numeric",label="mprior.size")
bmsMeth$parameters<-prm
bmsGrid<-function(x,y,len=NULL){
out<-expand.grid(mprior.size=seq(2,3,by=len))
out
}
bmsMeth$grid<-bmsGrid
bmsFit<-function(x,y,param, lev=NULL) {bms(cbind(y,x),burn=5000,iter=100000,nmodel=1000,mcmc="bd",g="UIP",mprior.size=param$mprior.size)}
bmsMeth$fit<-bmsFit
bmsPred<-function(modelFit,newdata,preProcess=NULL,submodels=NULL){predict(modelFit,newdata)}
bmsMeth$predict<-bmsPred

library(caret)
data.train<-data.frame(runif(100),runif(100),runif(100),runif(100),runif(100))#synthetic data for testing
bms(cbind(data.train[,1],data.train[,-1]),burn=5000,iter=100000,nmodel=1000,mcmc="bd",g="UIP",mprior.size=2)#function out of caret is working

preProcess=c('center','scale')
myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",initialWindow = 0.99*nrow(data.train), horizon = 1, fixedWindow = FALSE)
tune <- train(data.train[,-1],data.train[,1],preProcess=preProcess,method = bmsMeth,tuneLength=2,metric= "RMSE",trControl =myTimeControl,type="Regression")
```

Error I get :

> Error in train.default(data.train[, -1], data.train[, 1], preProcess =
>   preProcess,  :    Stopping In addition: Warning messages: 1: In
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :   model fit failed for Training1:
>   mprior.size=2 Error in method$fit(x = x, y = y, wts = wts, param =
>   tuneValue, lev = obsLevels,  :    unused arguments (wts = wts, last =
>   last, classProbs = classProbs, type = "Regression")
>
> 2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info =
>   trainInfo,  :   There were missing values in resampled performance
>   measures.

Comment: For purposes of searching for solutions, I think the exact English text to search for is `attempt to apply non-function`.

Comment: Thanks for your edition !

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible in a small example?

Comment: Well I thought I just did that, what do you need ?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I can't get it smaller (I already removed parameters and cross validation grid), but this is reproducible

Comment: Not a solution but probably a hint: because no `tuneGrid` argument was given to `train()` it tries to call `bmsMeth$grid` instead to create a grid. However, `bmsMeth$grid` is `NULL` too, which indeed is pas une fonction. Try passing a `tuneGrid` argument to `train()` or storing a grid creation function in `bmsMeth$grid`.

Comment: Well I hade a tuneGrid initially, but didn't work so I simplified at a maximum, but I will try again and post the correspondant code, thanks for your interest !

Comment: @WhiteViking, you're probably right, it is not the same kind of mistake but doesn't work, I must miss something

Comment: That link is pretty old. The site moved to [github](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html) a while back.

Answer (score 3):

Apparantly, I just had to put the arguments in the function even if I never use them :

```
bmsFit<-function(x,y,param, lev=NULL, last, weights, classProbs, ...) {bms(data.frame(y,x),burn=5000,iter=100000,nmodel=1000,mcmc="bd",g="UIP",mprior.size=param$mprior.size)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function bms() does not seem to exist ...

Comment: you can find it in the library(BMS)